# What does -d@- mean after a curl command?

Tags: linux, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

So for example, say you have:

```
curl -d@- http://localhost:8000
```

what does each part of -d@- mean? This type of thing is difficult to google and I couldn't find any info about it in the docs or curl --help.

Thanks guys.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that you actually looked at the documentation; this is reasonably explicitly covered there.

Answer (score 6):

The `-d@-` in this command line is explained as this.

`-d` is the Data flag defining what is sent in the POST request.
`@` means send the file after this character as the body of the POST request.
`-` means stdin.

So `-d@-` means to read from stdin to send to the URL as the body of the POST request.